# Entypo not supported in browser

Tags: asp.net, css, c#-4.0

I am using Entypo font. now some entypo font is not working safari(windows 7)
but it is working on safari (mac os)
and also Entypo Social Extention is not supported on some browser
what i can do for this problem  as client told me to use only entypo....

Technology asp.net(c# 4.0)

Answer (score 0):

Entypo doesn't fully work on Chrome 32+ - it can be fixed by updating the CSS file, details of which can be found in the following post:

- http://dquinn.net/how-to-fix-broken-font-icons-in-chrome-32-for-entypo-web-font-in-gumby-framework/